# What is the purpose of the 'y' sticky pattern modifier in JavaScript RegExps?

Tags: javascript, regex

MDN introduced the 'y' sticky flag for JavaScript RegExp. Here is a [documentation excerpt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

> **y**
>
> sticky; matches only from the index indicated by the lastIndex property of this regular expression in the target string (and does not attempt to match from any later indexes).

There's also an example:

```
var text = 'First line\nSecond line';
var regex = /(\S+) line\n?/y;

var match = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match[1]);        // prints 'First'
console.log(regex.lastIndex); // prints '11'

var match2 = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match2[1]);       // prints 'Second'
console.log(regex.lastIndex); // prints '22'

var match3 = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match3 === null); // prints 'true'
```

But there isn't actually any difference between the usage of the **g** global flag in this case:

```
var text = 'First line\nSecond line';
var regex = /(\S+) line\n?/g;

var match = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match[1]);        // prints 'First'
console.log(regex.lastIndex); // prints '11'

var match2 = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match2[1]);       // prints 'Second'
console.log(regex.lastIndex); // prints '22'

var match3 = regex.exec(text);
console.log(match3 === null); // prints 'true'
```

Same output. So I guess there might be something else regarding the 'y' flag and it seems that MDN's example isn't a real use-case for this modifier, as it seems to just work as a replacement for the 'g' global modifier here.

So, what could be a *real use-case* for this experimental 'y' sticky flag? What's its purpose in "matching only from the RegExp.lastIndex property" and what makes it differ from 'g' when used with `RegExp.prototype.exec`?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this article. It explains `y` flag as specified in ES6 draft, which slightly differs from what FF implemented. https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#sticky-flag

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *difference* between `y` and `g` is described in [Practical Modern JavaScript](https://github.com/mjavascript/practical-modern-javascript/blob/master/ch07.asciidoc#sticky-matching-flag-y):

> The sticky flag advances `lastIndex` like `g` but **only if a match is found
>   starting at `lastIndex`, there is no forward search**. The sticky flag **was added to improve the performance of writing lexical analyzers** using
>   JavaScript...

As for a real use case,

> It could be used **to require a regular expression match starting at position `n` where `n`
>   is what `lastIndex` is set to**. In the case of a non-multiline regular
>   expression, a `lastIndex` value of `0` with the sticky flag would be in
>   effect the same as starting the regular expression with `^` which
>   requires the match to start at the beginning of the text searched.

And here is an example from that blog, where the `lastIndex` property is manipulated before the `test` method invocation, thus forcing different match results:

```
var searchStrings, stickyRegexp;

stickyRegexp = /foo/y;

searchStrings = [
    "foo",
    " foo",
    "  foo",
];
searchStrings.forEach(function(text, index) {
    stickyRegexp.lastIndex = 1;
    console.log("found a match at", index, ":", stickyRegexp.test(text));
});
```

Result:

```
"found a match at" 0 ":" false
"found a match at" 1 ":" true
"found a match at" 2 ":" false
```

Comment: So it forces the pattern to match at that index (`1` in this case) and if it doesn't match, it won't even go straight in order to match at another offset higher than lastIndex? This is effectively like doing `text = " foo".substr(1);` and then trying to match against it using the RegExp `/^foo/`, am I right?

Comment: As you know, regex engine starts its work from left to right (unless there is a flag as in .NET, rightToLeft), and goes on looking for the first match. When we set the `lastIndex` to `1`, it means we are looking for `foo` at Position 1 in the input string. So, in this case, we just force the match only at Position 1. And then there is no matching, neither at the start of the line, nor at Position 1 at the next line, as there is no forward matching when we matched a text at the `lastIndex` position. It looks as if a single substring search at a specific position.

Comment: The given blog link no longer points to a valid page. This might be helpful: https://javascript.info/regexp-sticky

Comment: @t.888 Changed to  https://github.com/mjavascript/practical-modern-javascript/blob/master/ch07.asciidoc#sticky-matching-flag-y

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a difference in behaviour as showed below:

```
var text = "abc def ghi jkl"
undefined
var regexy = /\S(\S)\S/y;
undefined
var regexg = /\S(\S)\S/g;
undefined
regexg.exec(text)
Array [ "abc", "b" ]
regexg.lastIndex
3
regexg.exec(text)
Array [ "def", "e" ]
regexg.lastIndex
7
regexg.exec(text)
Array [ "ghi", "h" ]
regexg.lastIndex
11
regexg.exec(text)
Array [ "jkl", "k" ]
regexg.lastIndex
15
regexg.exec(text)
null
regexg.lastIndex
0
regexy.exec(text)
Array [ "abc", "b" ]
regexy.lastIndex
3
regexy.exec(text)
null
regexy.lastIndex
0
```

..but I have yet to fully understand what is going on there.

Comment: What is going wrong is that after the first match in `regexy`, the regex is stuck with a `lastIndex` with value _3_, which means that it will start the match from that the next time `exec` is called on `regexy`, starting from that _lastIndex_ (index 3, therefore starting from " def ghi jkl"), the regex is forced to match `\S(\S)\S`, and therefore three characters which are not space characters starting from **that** index, and not moving forward. As at index 3 the first character is a space, the regex doesn't match, hence the **null**. I guess this is what's going on, what do you think?

Comment: I think that's exactly it. So the matches have to be stack behind each other without a gap, right? Then I think the naming isn't awesome.

Comment: Right, yes, the name is not so intuitive, I would have called it "continuous", "unbroken" modifier or something like that...